# Screenshot em Python

Tags: python

Olá! Meu problema é o seguinte:
Eu quero fazer uma screenshot da tela do meu pc usando python, eu até consigo bater a screenshot, porém, a captura de tela só é salva após a execução do programa, digo, a print só é salva após meu código terminar de rodar... Tem alguma forma da screenshot salvar enquanto executo o programa?
Segue o código:

```
import pyautogui
import time

capturar = pyautogui.screenshot()
capturar.save('foto.jpg')

for a in range(1,10):
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Como eu disse, a captura de tela só é salva após o `for`, ou seja quando o código para de executar. Tem como ela ser salva antes da finalização da execução do programa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MODIFICADO EM 5/Jan/2021**

Acredito que seja isso que vc está querendo fazer:

```
import os
import pyautogui
import time

foto = 'foto.jpg'

pyautogui.screenshot(foto)  # Desta forma o pyautogui salva a imagem

if os.path.isfile(foto):
   print("Foto salva")

for a in range(1,10):
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)
```

A saída será

```
% python salva_screenshot.py
Foto salva
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: O problema persiste ainda... Ele salva a imagem apenas no fim da execução do código, gostaria que ele salvasse durante a execução.

Comment: Seria uma sequencia de imagem ?

Comment: Como assim sequencia de imagem? Você quer dizer varias fotos? Se for isso que vc quer dizer, devo falar que quero tirar apenas uma captura de tela e salva-la, mas antes do programa parar de executar

Comment: @Rcoletto, como vc está testando se a foto existe ou não? Modifiquei o post mostrando que salva antes do loop.

Comment: Eu executei o código que você enviou, aparentemente ele funciona, mas a foto só aparece nos meus arquivos quando ele para de executar.

Comment: O `os.path.isfile(foto)` testa se o arquivo está no seu sistema operacional... Veja que está! Como vc está testando "só aparece nos meus arquivos"?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Tive que reiniciar o pc, e depois dele fazer isso eu testei o código novamente e deu certo! Não sei exatamente o que houve, mas deu certo! Obrigado.

Comment: @Rcoletto que bom que está funcionando... Caso ache pertinente, dê uma lida [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)

Answer (score -1):

Coloca o código dentro de While True e captura a função com um evento do teclado

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard 
while True:

    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        print ('impresso')
```